# How to use the same output file from two commands which are piped in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe

Assuming I have the following batch comannd which works as expected.

```
file1.exe | file2.exe
```

Now I have the following requirement.
- Stderr from file1.exe should be written to a logfile
- Stdout and Stderr from file2.exe should be written to a logfile

This works, too

```
file1.exe 2>>file1.log | file2.exe >>file2.log 2>&1
```

However, what I really want is to have both outputs in the same file. This fails because `file.log` is used by another process

```
file1.exe 2>>file.log | file2.exe >>file.log 2>&1
```

Here is a real world example to demonstrate the issue.

```
echo test 2>>file.log | findstr t 1>>file.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
( echo test | findstr t ) >>file.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will pipe all the data to findstr:

```
echo test 2>&1 | findstr "^" >file.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Yepp, but this will not work for me. `echo` and `findstr` are just examples to reproduce the error. The first commands output will be piped to sevenzip `7z.exe u -sifile.txt backup.7z` This will store a compressed file `file.txt` inside an archive `backup.7z`. What I want is the error output from the first command plus the output from sevenzip in one log file. With your code, the error messages would be included in my zip file.

Comment: It helps to ask questions with real details.

Comment: A detailed explaination what the first command does would just distract from the real task. `Stderr from file1.exe should be written to a logfile - Stdout and Stderr from file2.exe should be written to a logfile... This fails because file.log is used by another process` You just assumed the second command would just output to console and even in that case findstr would filter the error, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to execute this task in properly real time, you can also create two different temporary files:

> file1.exe 2 >> temp1.log | file2.exe >> temp2.log

And then you can print the second text file to the first one:

> echo. >> temp1.log && type temp2.log >> temp1.log
>   REM "echo." leaves a blank line in the output file